# How to stop onDraw() methods causing jerky scrolling of a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, bitmap, android-view

I have a `ListView`, and its child `Views` contain many calls to the `Canvas` on their `onDraw()` methods (such as `drawPath()` etc). I have found that when you scroll the `ListView`, the calls to `onDraw` (which are frequent) cause really jerky scrolling. I have found that you can eliminate this problem by replacing each `View` in the `ListView` by an `ImageView` where the image `Bitmap` is created from the original `View` using code like this.

```
view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
int bitmapWidth = view.getMeasuredWidth();
int bitmapHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();
view.layout(0, 0, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
view.draw(canvas);
```

This solves the problem of jerky scrolling. However the problem is that the method `Bitmap.createBitmap()` seems prone to throw an `OutOfMemoryError`. I have read advice on this site that you should never use this method. Does anyone know how I can best get around these problems?

Comment: what are you trying to show in your listview?

Comment: The views are very complicated. I use the various Canvas methods to draw text, lines, polygons, circles etc. The more of these methods I use, the jerkier the scrolling becomes. I think it's because android has to calculate the graphics each time. Replacing the View by a Bitmap means that these calculations only need to be done once.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1) Post more source

2) read http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

3) consider using an ArrayAdapter http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

You may want to track the number of times you call create bitmap, and how garbage collection is being handled there.  If you're not properly recycling your views, and you're creating lots of these bitmaps you going to very rapidly overwhelm your available memory.

For efficiency in this regard you can look at bitmap caching, ala:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My source is spread over 100s of classes so it's difficult to post more details. I'm already using an ArrayAdapter and have read the first link before. However the LruCache class (which I'd never heard of) mentioned in the third link looks promising. I'll give it a go and post more code if I don't get anywhere.

Comment: You might look into extending BaseAdapter yourself, some of the default implementions have some limitations that you may need to work through.  For what its worth I had an app that loaded and scrolled smoothly through tens of thousands of images, so what you're doing is viable if you're smart with your resources.

Answer (score 0):

Months later I have found a solution. Before I started using `Bitmap`s I was unwittingly allocating a large number of objects in the `onDraw()` methods. I was not getting any warnings from Android Studio because the `new` keyword was being used in a method called from `onDraw` rather than `onDraw` itself. I discovered that if you accidentally write `new Paint()` in a loop rather than reusing a `Paint` object, it seriously harms the performance of scrolling.

I now only have a handful of `Paint` objects and a single `Path` object in my application (and no `Bitmap`s at all) and all these problems have disappeared. Hopefully somebody reading this will learn from my mistake!